# PHP if Statement for my simple login system not working as expected

Tags: php, html, sql

I've creatde a simple PHP login system, I am facing some problems with my code crosschecking the username and password. It isn't working as expected as the page is not moving me to the `management.php` page.

I have managed to confirm a successful connection to the database. The query is also correct as I am able to echo the Database Query onto the page (early tests). However, now that I have moved forward and started inserting if statements to get some form of authentication going, the page does not redirect me anymore... Could someone please take a closer look?

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","customer");
if($db){
  $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']); 
  $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']); 
  $username = stripslashes($username); 
  $password = stripslashes($password); 
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']); 
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password';";
  $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

  }elseif($username == $row['username'] && $password == $row['password']) {
    header("Location: management.php");
    echo $username;
  }else{


    die("Connection Failed" . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
}
?>
```

below is my form that should trigger my php code. everything should be working accordingly here.

```html
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>username</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" class="textinput"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" class="textinput"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Please Criticise and help find where I am going wrong.

Comment: I'm not answering your question but just giving you some pointers, :  Dont store your passwords in plain text, use `password_hash();` and `password_verify();` to hash your passwords,  use prepared statements, with **mysqli or PDO**

Comment: Common man, just give me the answer ;D! thanks for the heads up

Comment: In the last `else` statement, have you tried using `echo` to see if it's failing the previous `elseif()`?

Comment: Does `$row['username']` & `$row['password']` actually match `$username` & `$password` ?

Comment: Have tried redirecting `header("Location: management.php");` within your environment to see if it works?

Comment: What's the point of strip_tags and stripslashes here?  You can always pull a row based on the username, and then see if the passwords match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem within your query is within the `elseif` what are you currently saying in your query is if database have connect do the sql query then you have an elseif statement, your code runs I doubt it ever reach the elseif part as the if($db) is always true.

> NB: As I have stated in my comment above never store password in plain
>   text, php provides better ways of hashing your password, with
>   `password_hash();` and `password_verify()` You can read about them in
>   the php manual

[1. Password_hash();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

[2. Password_verify();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Also you need to learn about prepared statements, with mysqli / pdo

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) is the introduction to [prepared statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "customer");
        if ($db) {
            $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
            $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
            $username = stripslashes($username);
            $password = stripslashes($password);
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
            $sql      = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
            $query    = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            $row      = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);


            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                header("Location: management.php");
                echo $username;
            } else {

                die("Incorrect username / password");
            }
        } else {


            die("Connection Failed" . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for thoroughly answering my question and teaching me how to better my coding standard in terms of security. your a #bro

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. Try this

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","customer");
if($db){
  $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']); 
  $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']); 
  $username = stripslashes($username); 
  $password = stripslashes($password); 
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']); 
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password';";
  $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);



 if($username == $row['username'] && $password == $row['password']) {
    header("Location: management.php");

  }else{


    die("Connection Failed" . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: you are Incorrect sir. But I still appreciate your attempt at helping.